# Why does my second Ext.Msg close immediately after the first?

Tags: sencha-touch

Firstly, here is my code:

```
Ext.Msg.show({
    title: 'Username',
    msg: 'Please enter your username',
    buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OKCANCEL,
    prompt:{ maxlength : 180, autocapitalize : false },
    modal: true,
    fn: function(buttonId, text) {
        console.log("OK ("+text+"), what is you password?");
        if (buttonId == 'ok')
        {
            Ext.Msg.show({
                title: 'Password',
                msg: 'Please enter your password',
                buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OKCANCEL,
                prompt:{ maxlength : 180, autocapitalize : false },
                modal: true,
                fn: function(buttonId2, text2) {
                    if (buttonId == 'ok')
                    {
                        console.log("OK ("+text+", "+text2+"), attempting login..");
                    }
                },
                icon: Ext.MessageBox.INFO
            });
        }
    },
    icon: Ext.MessageBox.INFO
});
```

My problem is that when I press OK on the first messagebox, the second one appears for less then a second and then closes too, without me pressing OK on the second messagebox.

Ideally, of course, I'd display both username and password inputs in the same Messagebox, but I can't figure out how to do this.

All help appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The static show method on Ext.Msg that you are calling basically reconfigures the previous MessageBox and so is getting confused when hiding and showing again.

You should create a new instance of the Ext.MessageBox class and call the show method of that object so it will use independent instances.

```
var msg = new Ext.MessageBox().show({
    title: 'Username',
    msg: 'Please enter your username',
    buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OKCANCEL,
    prompt:{ maxlength : 180, autocapitalize : false },
    modal: true,
    fn: function(buttonId, text) {
        console.log("OK ("+text+"), what is you password?");
        if (buttonId == 'ok')
        {
            var msg2 = new Ext.MessageBox().show({
                title: 'Password',
                msg: 'Please enter your password',
                buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OKCANCEL,
                prompt:{ maxlength : 180, autocapitalize : false },
                modal: true,
                fn: function(buttonId2, text2) {
                    if (buttonId == 'ok')
                    {
                        console.log("OK ("+text+", "+text2+"), attempting login..");
                    }
                },
                icon: Ext.MessageBox.INFO
            });
        }
    },
    icon: Ext.MessageBox.INFO
});
```

Although this works, I would recommend you make a custom form panel containing both the fields and collect the information that way.

Hope this helps.
Stuart